ERROR: types/values length mismatch
struct EnforcedOptionParam {
    uint32 eid; 
    uint16 msgType;
    bytes options; 
}

function setEnforcedOptions(EnforcedOptionParam[] calldata _enforcedOptions) public virtual onlyOwner {
    _setEnforcedOptions(_enforcedOptions);
}

I am using tronbox console to call the contract:
tronbox(shasta)> OtcMarket.deployed().then(otc => otc.setEnforcedOptions(
[
[40245, 0, "0x0003010021010000000000000000000000000098968000000000000000000000000000e4e1c0"],
[40245, 1, "0x000301001101000000000000000000000000000186a001000104"]
])
);

I am getting the following error:
ERROR: types/values length mismatch (count={"types":1,"values":2},
value={"types":["tuple(uint32,uint16,bytes)[]"],
"values":[
[40245,0,"0x0003010021010000000000000000000000000098968000000000000000000000000000e4e1c0"],
[40245,1,"0x000301001101000000000000000000000000000186a001000104"]
]}, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.7.0)

